# Adding a header to a '|' delimited CSV file in Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, csv, powershell-3.0

I was wondering if anybody knows a way to achieve this without breaking/mesing with the data itself?

I have a CSV file which is delimited by '|' which was created by retrieving data from Sharepoint using an SPQuery and exported using out-file (because export-csv is not an option since I would have to store the data in a variable and this would eat at the RAM of the server, querying remotely unfortuntely will also not work so i have to do this on the server itself). Nevertheless I have the Data i need but i want to perform some manipulations and move and autocalc certain data within an excel file and export the said excel file.

The problem I have right now is that I sort of need a header to the file. I have tried using the following code:

```
$header ="Name|GF_GZ|GF_Title|GF_UniqueId|GF_OldId|GFURL|GF_ITEMREDIRECTID"
$file = Import-Csv inputfilename.csv -Header $header | Export-Csv D:\outputfilename.csv
```

In powershell but the issue here is that when i perform the second Export-Csv it will delimit at anything that has a comma and thus remove it, i sort of need the data to remain intact.

I have tried playing with the -Delimit '|' setting both on the import and the export path but no matter what i do it seems to be cutting off the data. Is there a better way to simply add a row at the Top (a header) without messing with the already existing file structure?
I have found out that using a delimiter such as -delimiter '°' or any other special case character will remove my problem entirely, but i can never be sure if such a character is going to show up in the dataset and thus (as stated already) am looking for a more "elegant" solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is to create the original CSV with the headers first.  Then when you are exporting the SharePoint data, use the switch -Append in the Out-File command to append the SP data to the CSV.

Comment: Yes this is an option that I have considered, but i want the whole process to be automated as much as humanely possible and the next steps (which i still haev to code) involve processnig data in excel from multiple output files and then performing calculations so that its already preformatted for my superiors to be able to see data quickly. So while this technically is a solution its not something that helps me in the automation part. Thanks for the comment though i appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure I follow since you are automatically building the CSV with the headers first and then appending to it.  Do you need the PowerShell script on how to create a CSV with headers?  I assumed you could figure that one out.  I did not mean to indicate that you should manually create this file.

Comment: This is my code
do {
    $itemcoll = $spSourceList.GetItems($query);
         
    foreach ($item in $itemcoll) {

        #write-host $($item.Url) $($item["Sachbearbeiter"]);
        $Name = $item["Name"];
        $GF_GZ = $item["GF_GZ"];
        $GF_Title = $item["GF_Title"];
        $GF_UniqueId = $item["UniqueId"];
        $GF_OldId = $item["OldItemId"];
        #$ITyp2 = $item["Content Type"];
       
         write-output "$Name|$GF_GZ|$GF_Title|$GF_UniqueId|$GF_OldId|$GFURL|$ITEMREDIRECTID" | Out-File -append D:\BG_SOF_SP01_Abgeschlossen_14Jan.csv #$($item.Url)|$($item.UniqueId)
    }

Comment: THe reason i am not saving the query output to a variable first and adding data using $var += result from loop is the sheer amount of datasize is killing the RAM of the server (powershell using 3-4 Gigabyte of RAM just to temporarily save the data), whereas simlpy appending using out-file will work.

I am well aware that Powershell supports -append for the export-csv command since 3.0 or 4.0 but we dont have that version availble on the server. So out-file is the only option.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, but Out-File supports the -Append switch and has since version 3.0.  What version of SPS are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even bother messing with it in csv format.

```
$header ="Name|GF_GZ|GF_Title|GF_UniqueId|GF_OldId|GFURL|GF_ITEMREDIRECTID"
$in_file = '.\inputfilename.csv'
$out_file = '.\outputfilename.csv'
$x = Get-Content $in_file
Set-Content $out_file -Value $header,$x
```

There's probably a more eloquent/refined two-liner for some of this, but this should get you what you need.